# Weird results with collision between Path2D.Double() Objects

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, collision

I'm using Java Graphics2D and Path2D to work with collision with some diamonds. However, I am getting weird results. There does not seem to be collision until the traveling black diamond has moved outside the blue diamond where the collision function returns true for a few seconds and then stops as the black diamond travels onwards. The best way for you to get a picture of what is going on is to simply test out the code for yourself.

What should happen is that when the black diamond should stop as soon as it hits the blue diamond. Simple. That does not seem to be happening here however. As the black diamond stops outside the blue diamond.

The main goal of this experiement is to work with isometric projections. If you know a better way i can do that, please tell me!

main.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    static int WIDTH;
    static int HEIGHT;

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(110, 110, 100, 100);

    ArrayList<GraphicalObject> objs = new ArrayList<GraphicalObject>();

    int targetFPS = 60;
    int currentFPS = targetFPS;



    int boxx = -500;
    int boxy = 0;
    boolean rising = false;
    boolean ontop = false;

    long oldFpsLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long newFpsLoop = oldFpsLoop;
    int ticks = 0;

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000/targetFPS, this);

    public Main(){
        timer.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        requestFocus();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i=0; i < objs.size(); i++){
            GraphicalObject cobj = objs.get(i);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();


            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
            g2.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);

            if (cobj.type.equals("text")){
                g2.setColor(cobj.color);

                g2.drawString(cobj.content, cobj.x, cobj.y);
            } else if (cobj.type.equals("rect")){
                g2.setColor(cobj.color);


                /**/
                AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
                at.setToRotation(Math.toRadians(0), WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
                at.translate(WIDTH/2-cobj.w/2, HEIGHT/2-cobj.h/2);
                g2.setTransform(at);
                /**/
                g2.drawRect(cobj.x, cobj.y, cobj.w, cobj.h);
                g2.fill(cobj.projection);
            }

            g2.dispose();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        WIDTH = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        HEIGHT = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
        Main main = new Main();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("360 ATTACK");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.add(main);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ticks++;
        newFpsLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (newFpsLoop - oldFpsLoop > 1000){
            oldFpsLoop = newFpsLoop;
            currentFPS = ticks;
            if (currentFPS < targetFPS){
                for (int i=0; i<targetFPS-currentFPS;i++){
                    logic();
                }
            }
            ticks = 0;
        }

        logic();
        repaint();
    }
    public void logic(){

        objs = new ArrayList<GraphicalObject>();
        objs.add(new GraphicalObject("fps", "text", 0, 10, "FPS: " + currentFPS, Color.BLACK));
        objs.add(new GraphicalObject("base", "rect", 0, 0, 200, 200, Color.BLUE));
        if (ontop == false){
            objs.add(new GraphicalObject("box", "rect", boxx, boxy, 20, 20, Color.BLACK));
            objs.add(new GraphicalObject("top","rect", -100, -100, 200, 200, Color.RED));

        } else {
            objs.add(new GraphicalObject("top", "rect", -100, -100, 200, 200, Color.RED));
            objs.add(new GraphicalObject("box", "rect", boxx, boxy, 20, 20, Color.BLACK));

        }

        GraphicalObject box = null;
        GraphicalObject base = null;
        GraphicalObject top = null;

        for (int i=0; i<objs.size();i++){
            String name = objs.get(i).name;
            if (name.equals("box")){
                box = objs.get(i);
            } else if (name.equals("base")) {
                base = objs.get(i);
            } else if (name.equals("top")){
                top = objs.get(i);
            }
        }

        if(collision(box, base)){
            boxx--;
        }

        if (rising){
            boxx--;
            boxy--;
        } else {
            boxx++;
        }  
    }
    public boolean collision(GraphicalObject a, GraphicalObject b){
        Area aArea = new Area(a.projection);
        Area bArea = new Area(b.projection);
        aArea.intersect(bArea);
        return !aArea.isEmpty();
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int c = e.getKeyCode();
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

GraphicalObject.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

public class GraphicalObject {

    int x, y, w, h;
    public Color color;
    public String type;
    public String content;
    public Path2D.Double projection;            
    public String name;

    public GraphicalObject(String name, String type, int x, int y, int w, int h, Color color){
        this.type = type;
        this.color = color;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.name = name;

        projection = new Path2D.Double();
        projection.moveTo(x+(w/5), y+(h/5));
        projection.lineTo(x+w, y);
        projection.lineTo(x+w-(w/5), y+h-(h/5));
        projection.lineTo(x,y+h);
        projection.lineTo(x+(w/5), y+(h/5));

    }
    public GraphicalObject(String name, String type, int x, int y, String content, Color color){
        this.name = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        this.type = type;
        this.content = content;
     } 
}
```

Comment: Care to explain all that code a bit, including what it is supposed to do, what it actually does, how exactly it's misbehaving, ....?

Comment: Added that to my question

Comment: you have a lot of problems; and the first one is that you consider yourself a high level programmer - whose advice did you follow to translate the graphics instead of the objects?? go and ask for clarification

Comment: Followed a mix of youtube tutorials to write out the base. Then just added my stuff ontop. It seems to work fine, other than the, collision problem of course.

Comment: I am new to java and i consider myself a high level programmer. Yes.

Comment: Then make this a "higher-level" program: separate your view from your model, use unit testing and mocking to help you debug the model, and learn to debug with a debugger.